# Biztalk Error: This Assembler cannot retrieve a document specification

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013

> There was a failure executing the send pipeline:
>   "Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines.XMLTransmit,
>   Microsoft.BizTalk.DefaultPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Source: "XML assembler" Send Port:
>   "WcfSendPort_SqlAdapterBinding_TableOp_dbo_User_Custom" URI:
>   "mssql://host/serverName/databaseTable?" Reason: This Assembler cannot
>   retrieve a document specification using this type:
>   "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/User#Select".

but the schema namespace is "http://schemas.microsoft.com/Sql/2008/05/TableOp/dbo/User1"
and the select node is : SelectQuery
after deploying make restart for host instance and nothing changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the message that hit's the Pipeline does not match any Deployed Schemas.  So, this error is only a symptom of the real problem, it is not a problem in itself.

First, "SelectQuery" is not a valid WCF SQL Element.  Do you mean Select/Query?

Next, it look like the schema was generated twice and you're using the wrong one.  I can tell because of "User**1**".

So, figure out which is the right one, User or User1.  Then make sure that is the one that's user where you expect and that it's deployed.